# Borrar row dinámicamente en una Datatable JQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

Mediante un botón inserto filas dinámicamente a una datatable, con otro boton de borrado en la última columna para tener la posibilidad de borrar la fila en la que me encuentro.

[image]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es el siguiente, cuando hago click en el botón de borrado de fila efectivamente me borra la fila, pero la datatable intérnamente mantiene los datos aunque la fila no se muestra.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando vuelvo a insertar una nueva fila, reaparece la fila de antes con la nueva fila creada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo borrar una fila definitívamente? muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Jorge, ¿puedes poner el código en texto? Facilita mucho más que podamos ayudarte. También estaría bien poder ver el HTML generado. Mira cómo crear un [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema se debe a que estas borrando manualmente "*la fila*" pero no el registro en la `DataTable`.

### Solución:

```
var t = $('#general').DataTable();
// ... código

// Borrar registro
t.on('click', 'button.del', function() {
  let $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

  // Le pedimos al DataTable que borre la fila
  t.row($tr).remove().draw(false);
});
```